# Arrangement and combination with repetition of elements, but without replacement.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Good morning !
I'm looking for the two general formulas (in one case the order is important, in the other not)

Case: How many configurations of 7 letters can we obtain with the 100 scrabble pieces, knowing that certain letters are in several copies. Configuration doesn't have to be an actual word.

If these were configurations of 100 elements we could have used the conventional permutation formulas, but the authorized configurations being 7 (or for any number different from the total of the elements of the set) I'm wondering how to calculate without manual counting.

(Please forgive me for any possible spelling errors. I don't speak English, but I am French speaking.)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.